# PostGIS error building with `make` in ./extensions: nothing to be done for 'comments'

Tags: postgis, source-code

I'm using code I checked out from SVN. Whenever I run `make` in `./extensions/`, I get

```
 make
for DIR in postgis  postgis_tiger_geocoder  postgis_topology address_standardizer; do \
    echo "---- Making all in ${DIR}"; \
    make -C "${DIR}" all || exit 1; \
done
---- Making all in postgis
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ecarroll/code/postgis/extensions/postgis'
mkdir -p sql_bits/
/usr/bin/perl -pe 's/BEGIN\;//g ; s/COMMIT\;//g' ../../postgis/postgis_for_extension.sql > sql_bits/postgis.sql
make -C ../../doc comments
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ecarroll/code/postgis/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'comments'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ecarroll/code/postgis/doc'
cp ../../doc/postgis_comments.sql sql_bits/postgis_comments.sql
cp: cannot stat '../../doc/postgis_comments.sql': No such file or directory
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'sql_bits/postgis_comments.sql' failed
make[1]: *** [sql_bits/postgis_comments.sql] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ecarroll/code/postgis/extensions/postgis'
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Whenever I run `make comments` in the root I get a small portion of those errors,

```
make comments
make -C doc comments
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ecarroll/code/postgis/doc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'comments'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ecarroll/code/postgis/doc'
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `xsltproc`,

```
16:02 < robe2> EvanCarroll: Looks like you are probably missing xsltproc
```

Install `xsltproc` (instructions in Ubuntu/Debian)

```
sudo apt-get install xsltproc;
```

Then,

```
make distclean;
./autogen.sh;
make;
```

And try again. It should work.

Comment: Was just about to point you at this thread: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-devel/2014-September/024543.html :-)

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I'm not out of the dark yet. =( I actually think this only addresses part of the original fail log, so I may have to update question.